# How to get tagname of a TEXT_NODE in java's org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, xml-parsing, w3c, xmlnode

In the documentation for this interface it states that textnodes all return "#text" for their names instead of the actual tag name. But for what i'm doing, the tag name is necessary.

```
// I'm using the following imports
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.EntityResolver;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;


// In the .xml input file
<country>US</country>  // This is a "text node" .getTextContent()
                       // returns "US", I need "country" and .getNodeName() 
                       // only returns "#text"
```

How could I access the tag name? This must be possible somehow, I don't mind a hackish solution.

Docs:

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what nodes are involved. This XML:

```
<country>US</country>
```

... contains *two* nodes:

- The `country` element
- The text node, with content of US

The element is *not* a text node, and the text node doesn't *have* an element name, because it's not an element. It's important to understand that these are different nodes. That's the source of all your confusion, I believe.

If you're currently looking at the text node, you could use `node.getParentNode().getNodeName()` to get the element name. Or from the element node, you could call `getTextContent()`.